# Circumventing UK Planning Law For 2m Boundaries

Tags: united-kingdom

Are these legal ways for a council to avoid dealing with the 2m boundary restriction for planning?

1. Only measure the fence months later (where the perpetrator has delayed it that long) when the ground level has been raised on the perpetrator's side of the fence after the council has repeatedly been told the ground was being raised with mud from another location of the garden?
2. Fail to measure the victim's side of the fence where the original ground level exists to see there are no changes, on the day they are finally allowed to measure the perpetrator's side of the fence?
3. Allow the perpetrator to detach a 3m+ high section of fence from the main fence, but keep it leaning against the main fence so it remains the same height?

Comment: Contact your council's planning department; they should be able to answer questions about what counts as a fence and how the height of a fence should be measured.

Comment: Front line council workers and police always try to help. The present council worker admitted the fence was not permitted and assured us something would be done. This present council worker has done fantastically by keeping this complaint going as long as it has and not buckling to the protagonist's fantasies and illusions. But, then strange things happen and issues such as rats, all day garden fires, thrown dogs mess, attacks on our property, etc, etc, are allowed to continue indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

### Enforcement of laws is discretionary

A council (or the police, or immigration, etc) decide whether they are going to enforce the law or not and how they will go about doing so.

If your rights have been violated then it’s up to you to enforce them by suing the person who did so.